# DirectoryCatalog.LoadedFiles one line foreach not working

Tags: c#, mef

I'm currently trying to output all loaded files from a DirectoryCatalog to the console by using one line foreach

**Code:**

```
DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".");

Array.ForEach(catalog.LoadedFiles, x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

That will give the following error:

> The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
> specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I try something like that (specifying the type argument with explicit casting):

```
Array.ForEach((ReadOnlyCollection<string>)catalog.LoadedFiles, x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

And it still doesn't work

**Note:**

This code works normally:

```
 foreach (var loadedFile in catalog.LoadedFiles)
 {
       Console.WriteLine(loadedFile);
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Array.ForEach<T> act on single dimension array. What is the type that LoadedFiles enclose ?

Comment: @Nair ReadOnlyCollection<string>

Comment: Sorry. That was clear from question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DirectoryCatalog.LoadedFiles` property return a `ReadOnlyCollection` of files and that is not an  implicit array. Here, the `ForEach<T>` method expects an array (single dimension) with elements of type `T`. In this case, you first need to convert `ReadOnlyCollection` to an array before accessing it. You could use `ToArray()` extension method on `ReadOnlyCollection` to convert it into array first before applying for `ForEach<T>`.

```
var files= DirectoryCatalog.LoadedFiles.ToArray();
```

Alternately, you could use `CopyTo` method on ReadOnlyCollection

```
string[] files= new string[theObject.TheProperty.Count];
DirectoryCatalog.LoadedFiles.CopyTo(files, 0);
```